# How do I set up basic routing for .NET WEBAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to learn .NET Web API so I decided to follow this very simple introduction:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

However, I can't even get this working.  I copied and pasted code directly to make sure I wasn't making some mistake, but when I run it, trying to access a path such as api/products/2 returns a 404.

Looking at my project, I didn't see any method of routing a path to the controller.  The only thing relevant in Web.config is:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

I had no WebApiConfig.cs, which seems to be required, so after some searching, I came up with this, which seems to be something of a default:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

That doesn't seem to work either.  Currently I just that WebApiConfig.cs and the code described in the guide I linked above.  Does anybody know what else I might be missing?

Note: I'm using Visual Studio Community.  I think the professional versions may help with wiring this stuff up, but I'm going to have to do it manually.

Edit: Adding full code:

Product.cs

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

ProductControllers.cs

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[] 
    { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the action method you are trying to invoke look like?

Comment: can you paste the code for the productscontroller.cs please?

Comment: Added full code (same as is in the link)

Comment: The action, when I just put in a webbrowser location bar should be a GET.  So http://localhost:29886/api/products should call GetAllProducts(), or at least that is the theory or goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you registering the route is not standard.

Here is the command way of registering route. The reason is you will be registrating filters same way later.

### Global.asax

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
      // RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
      // FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   }
}
```

### WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
      );       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working:

Created global.aspx with:

```
<script runat="server">
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        WebApiConfig.Register(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
</script>
```

Changed WebApiConfig.cs to:

```
using System.Web.Http;

public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Works fine now.  I just had to figure out how to register the routes.